# Why std::is_invocable<std::decay_t<void(int&)>, std::decay_t<int>>::value is false?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::is_invocable<std::decay_t<void(int&)>, std::decay_t<int>>::value
```

evaluates to false.

But

`void(int&)`
decays to
`void*(int&)`

and 
`int`
to 
`int`

and I can use `std::invoke` like this:

```
void f(int&);
...
auto* fp = f;
int i = 0;
std::invoke(fp, i);
```

I bumped into this when I was looking at `std::thread` constructor:

```
 template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args,
             typename = _Require<__not_same<_Callable>>>
      explicit
      thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
      {
        static_assert( __is_invocable<typename decay<_Callable>::type,
                                      typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
          "std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues"
          );
```

I understand why passing references to `std::thread`'s constructor is disouraged (we still can use `std::ref()`) but I cannot understand why `void *(int&)` cannot be invoked with `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::is_invocable<..., int>` attempts to use an `int` **rvalue** as the argument. It's equivalent to `std::is_invocable<..., int &&>`.

Use `std::is_invocable<..., int &>`.

---

> **[`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable)**
>
> ...Formally, determines whether `INVOKE(declval<Fn>(), declval<ArgTypes>()...)` is well formed...

Even if we ignore what `INVOKE` is, you can see that `is_invocable` is defined using `std::declval<ArgType>()`, which returns `ArgType &&`.

`ArgType &&` is, well, an rvalue reference. Unless `ArgType` is an lvalue reference, in which case `ArgType &&` is equivalent to `ArgType` and is an lvalue reference (according to the reference collapsing rules).